# Bind a Dictionary to a SQLAlchemy Model for Update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I have a Dictionary (from a WTForm) that has keys in it that match fields in my SQLAlchemy Model.

```
class Company(database.Model):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id = database.Column(database.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = database.Column(database.String(255), nullable=False)
    address = database.Column(database.String(255), nullable=False)
    ...
```

And a Dictionary:

```
{"name": "Apple Inc", "address": "1 Infinite Loop", ...}
```

Is there any easy way to set the Model's attributes to the matching Dictionary values, or do I need to follow the x = y pattern?

```
company.name = company_dict["name"]
company.address = company_dict["address"]...
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you actually want to create the record it should be as simple as:

```
company = Company.create(**company_dict)
```

Or for an update:

```
company.update(**company_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately it's for an update (I've edited the title).